# MySQL if statement conditional join

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement

I am trying to do something like

```
SELECT * from accounttable, peopletable, companytable 
WHERE if accounttable.account_type = company 
JOIN companytable 
WHERE companytable.id = accounttable.company_id 
ELSE IF accounttable.account_type = = person 
JOIN peopletable 
WHERE peopletable.id = accounttable.person_id
```

I'm sorry its a bit sqlenglish, but I really don't know how to write it out.

Comment: TELL ME YOUR TABLE SCHEMA AND RELATION between these tables.. you have a lot of syntax error

Comment: How can you write a query if you don't know what you want it to do? Please try to describe in words what you want. It will help yourself too. Often you see the solution as soon as you start describing the problem.

Comment: Reading the pseudo-query that has been written, it appears @Akshat wants to join `accounttable` on `peopletable`  and `companytable` depending on the value of `account_type`. Fairly straight forward to me.

Comment: i tried to  write it as a statement but stackoverflow codified the entire thing

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about something like:

```
SELECT * 
from accounttable
left join peopletable ON (accounttype = 'person' AND peopletable.id = accounttable.person_id)
left join companytable ON (accounttype = 'company' AND companytable.id = accounttable.company_id)
```

I'll join against both tables, so you'll have fields of all three tables in the output. The fields from `peopletable` will be `NULL` if `accounttype != 'person'`, and those of `companytable` will be `NULL` where `accounttype != 'company'`.

You can find more on the `LEFT JOIN` syntax in places like [here](https://encrypted.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=left%20join)...

Comment: Excellent works perfectly, (third line peopletable.id is supposed to be companytable.companyid) very clever way to use that acountype=xx and 'and' together!

Comment: @Akshat fixed the answer to include your note on the typo ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT a.*, p.*, c.* from accounttable a
LEFT JOIN peopletable p ON (a.person_id = p.id AND a.account_type = 'person')
LEFT JOIN companytable c ON (a.company_id = c.id AND a.account_type = 'company')
```

Note that a,p,c are aliases for the full tablenames, this saves on typing.

This query will give all `null` for either p.* or c.* in a row.
You can rewrite the select part like so:

```
SELECT 
  a.id, a.accounttype
  , COALESCE(p.name, c.name) as name
  , COALESCE(p.address, c.address) as address
....
FROM .....
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: @diEcho : Romain had given fast answer, no ?

Answer (score 0):

IT MUST BE like below ( as far as i understand )

```
SELECT a.*,p.*,c.* 
FROM accounttable a
LEFT JOIN companytable c ON c.id = a.company_id AND a.account_type = 'company'
LEFT JOIN peopletable p ON p.id = a.person_id AND  a.account_type = 'person'
```

Comment: and i din't voed down you instead i tell your mistake honestly.